# How to use variable as attribute value in xpath using php?

Tags: php, string, variables, xpath

This works

```
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id="103"]');
```

I am trying to replace `103` by a variable namely `$id`.
I tried

```
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id=$id]');
```

and

```
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id=".$id."]');
```

None work.

What is the appropriate syntax for putting a variable in xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you writed `$id` in string, php use it like string. You should close quote like

```
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id="'.$id.'"]');
```

Or write variable in `{}`

```
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id="{$id}"]');
```

Comment: $feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id="'.$id.'"]');
this worked. The second one with curly brackets didn't. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your question already answer from Mohammad
but i give a more fully example with [0] at the end of the line to avoid more rows for some usages

```
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id="'.$id.'"])[0];
```

also if you want result from xml with some others values inside to the root where use @attribute

```
$day= $_GET['Day']; 
$feed = $xml->xpath('//room[@id="'.$id.'"]/Day'.$day.'')[0];
```

this mean if you have a xml file like harder code you can cal a day dynamic